# Protege, reasoner doesn't find inconsistencies in individuals

Tags: ontology, protege

Tomorrow I've to consign a relation with an ontology made in protege, but I think I did all wrong. I wanted to make an ontology related to a PC list. Each PC has CPU, GPU and Motherboard. The CPU must be compatible with some motherboard (isCompatibleWith some Motherboard), the PC must contain exactly one CPU, one Motherboard and at least 1 GPU.
Now, I organized the classes like this:
[ontology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5TkG.png)
I inserted various HW components, and made a PC that contains only one CPU (i5-2500k). However the reasoner doesn't show any error, shouldn't tell me that the PC must have the mobo and the GPU?
Did I made this all wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The Open World Assumption allows the reasoner to accept a situation as you describe - it infers that a motherboard exists, but it does not know which one.

In order to find out if your individual with only one CPU is a valid computer, you should design the ontology so that, given an individual, it is classified as a computer only if it matches all requirements.

For example, Computer equivalentClass min 1 hasMotherboard and min 1 hasCPU. Now, if an individual is not known to be a Computer but has a motherboard and a CPU, the reasoner will classify it as such; individuals with no motherboard will be excluded; however, you need to specify that explicitly - as in stating these individuals are instances of max 0 hasMotherboard.